# Simple search form that redirects to ?s=searched terms

Tags: php, url

I want to make a simple form that redirects the user to "?=whateverhetypes". I'm sure it's easy but I just grasped the basics of sending variables through the url and I don't know how.

I suppose this would be the form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

What's the shortest way to do it? Thakns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Set `action` to be the URL of the file you would like the form to redirect to (for example `action="/url/script.php"`). Leave it blank to submit onto the current page.

Note how I renamed your text field to be just `s` so that when the form is submitted it will go to `/url/script.php?s=searched terms` like you have asked in the title of your question.